# Python trying to place keyword arguments after *args

Tags: python, python-2.x, variadic-functions, keyword-argument

I'm a bit confused about using `*args`.

I want to write a function that takes a variable number of arguments but can still use the advantage of defining a predefined value for a keyword argument.

But it's not possible to write a function like this:

```
def foo(*args, bar = "foo"):
    print bar, args
```

It's just possible to write it like this:

```
def foo2(bar = "foo", *args):
    print bar, args
```

But then I call `foo2` and pass the first argument it overrides the default value for `bar`!.

```
foo2("somevalue")
somevalue ()
```

Is where a way of doing this better ??

I know I could write it like this:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["bar"] = "foo"
```

but something like the first method definition (which yields a syntax error) is more intuitive from my point of view.

Comment: If you upgrade to Python 3.x, you *can* use the first form (see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would use `kwargs` and do the assignment in the call not the definition:

```
def foo2(*args, **kwargs):     # kwargs takes our key/values arguments
    print args, kwargs

foo2(1, 2, 3, bar="foo")       # bar is assigned to in call when using kwargs
```

Which gives:

```
(1, 2, 3) {'bar': 'foo'}
```

You could use `get` to set `foo` as a default for `bar` like so:

```
def foo2(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs["bar"] = kwargs.get("bar", "foo") # if bar is not set use foo as val
    print args, kwargs

foo2(1, 2, 3, bar="foo")
foo2(1, 2, 3, bar="notfoo")
foo2(1, 2, 3)
```

So that `kwargs["bar"]` is always `foo` unless explicitly changed:

```
(1, 2, 3) {'bar': 'foo'}
(1, 2, 3) {'bar': 'notboo'}
(1, 2, 3) {'bar': 'foo'}
```

Comment: I thought there would be another way to still place the default value in the method signature. But I just took this solution because I cannot switch to Python 3. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 12):

Can you switch to python 3 ?, In Python 3 you can use your first approach:

```
def foo(*args, bar = 'default_value'):
    print (args, bar)

foo(bar = 'newval')
foo('hola2')
```

You'll get:

```
() newval
('hola2',) default_value
```